# Unexpected Execution in Do-While Loop

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    do
    {
        cout << "Input a number (1 - 8): " << endl;
        cin >> number;
    }
    while (number < 0 || number > 8);
}
```

Why do the numbers 0 and 8 break out of the loop even though the while expressions are not satisfied?  0 < 0 == false and 8 > 8 == false?

Comment: The loop repeats if the condition is **true**.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the condition in your `do-while` loop is checking if your number is less than 0 or greater than 8. If the condition is true the loop repeats until your number is within the range from 0 to 8. The loop repeats as long as the condition is true. I think you are trying user to input a number in the range 1 to 8, if the input is out of this range, you want to keep asking the user to input a correct number. If this is the case, you need to edit your `while` condition this way:

```cpp
while (number < 1 || number > 8);
```